# Trying to accomplish a custom post and shortcode to connect external Database

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am trying out some wordpress stuff, but once I activate a plug in with the following code, the whole server gets slow. But when I use the same API without this plug in activated it all is pretty fast.

Can you guys help me, telling me what is wrong and maybe show me how to do it better.

I try to 1. Add a custom post type and 2. for now have it possible to receive external DB information about a profile with using a shortcode.

```
   <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Virtueel Assistent CP
Description: Custom Post plug-in voor virtuele assistenten
Author: Rico Otto - 2lemon
*/

// Our custom post type function
function create_virtueelassistent() {

    register_post_type( 'virtueelassistent',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Virtueel Assistent' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'VirtueelAssistent' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'virtueelassistent'),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_virtueelassistent' );


/*
* Creating a function to create our CPT
*/

function virtueel_assistent_cp() {

    // Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
        $labels = array(
            'name'                => _x( 'Virtueel Assistent', 'Post Type General Name' ),
            'singular_name'       => _x( 'Virtueel Assistent', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
            'menu_name'           => __( 'Virtueel Assistenten' ),
            'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent VA' ),
            'all_items'           => __( 'Alle VAs' ),
            'view_item'           => __( 'Bekijk VA' ),
            'add_new_item'        => __( 'Voeg Nieuwe VA toe' ),
            'add_new'             => __( 'Nieuwe VA' ),
            'edit_item'           => __( 'Wijzig VA' ),
            'update_item'         => __( 'Update VA' ),
            'search_items'        => __( 'Zoek VA' ),
            'not_found'           => __( 'Niet Gevonden' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Niet Gevonden in Prullenbak' ),
        );

    // Set other options for Custom Post Type

        $args = array(
            'label'               => __( 'virtueelassistent' ),
            'description'         => __( 'Virtueel assistent profiel' ),
            'labels'              => $labels,
            // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
            // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'skills' ),
            /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
            * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
            * is like Posts.
            */ 
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
        );

        // Registering your Custom Post Type
        register_post_type( 'virtueelassistent', $args );

    }

    /* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
    * Containing our post type registration is not 
    * unnecessarily executed. 
    */

    add_action( 'init', 'virtueel_assistent_cp', 0 );


    function do_getVa(){
        global $wpdb;
        $post = get_post();
        $VaID = $post->ID;

        $custom_url = '31.186.173.38:3032/profile/' . $VaID;
        $curl = curl_init($custom_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $answer = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $res1 = json_decode($answer);
        $profile_image = 'http://vabusinessacademy.2citroenen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Liesbeth-de-Korte.jpeg';
        $content = '';
        $content = $content . '<div class="entry-content" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Product"> 
                                        <div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 et_section_regular">
                                                <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0"> 
                                                        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_0 et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child"> 
                                                                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_team_member et_pb_team_member_0 et_pb_bg_layout_light clearfix">
                                                                        <div class="et_pb_team_member_image et-waypoint et_pb_animation_off">
                                                                                <img property="image" src="' . $res1->profile_image . '" alt="Virtueel assistent '. $res1->name .'">
                                                                        </div> 
                                                                        <div class="et_pb_team_member_description">
                                                                        <span property="brand" style="display:none">VA Business Academy</span>
                                                                                <h3 class="et_pb_module_header" property="name">' . $res1->name . '</h3> 
                                                                                <p property="description">' . $res1->bio . '</p>' . 
                                                                                '<span property="mpn" style="display: none;">' . $VaID . '</span>' .
                                                                                '<div property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating" class="average-rating">
                                                                                    <span property="ratingValue">'. $res1->average_rating .'</span> score, gebaseerd op <span property="reviewCount">'.$res1->rating_count.'</span> reviews
                                                                                    <span property="bestRating" style="display:none;">' .$res1->rating_best.'</span>
                                                                    <span property="worstRating" style="display:none;">' .$res1->rating_worst.'</span><div>' ;

        $content = $content .                                           '</div> <!-- .et_pb_team_member_description --> 
                                                                        <div class="average-rating">' . $res1->average_rating .  '</div>';

        if(property_exists ($res1, 'facebook_link')){$facebook_link = $res1->facebook_link;}
        if(property_exists ($res1, 'twitter_link')){$twitter_link = $res1->twitter_link;}
        if(property_exists ($res1, 'google_link')){$google_link = $res1->google_link;}
        if(property_exists ($res1, 'linkedin_link')){$linkedin_link = $res1->linkedin_link;}


        $content = $content . '                                                 <ul class="et_pb_member_social_links">';
        if(property_exists ($res1, 'facebook_link')){
                $content = $content .                                                   '<li><a href="' . $facebook_link . '" class="et_pb_font_icon et_pb_facebook_icon"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>';
        }
        if(property_exists ($res1, 'twitter_link')){
                $content = $content .                                                   '<li><a href="' . $twitter_link . '" class="et_pb_font_icon et_pb_twitter_icon"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>';
        }
        if(property_exists ($res1, 'google_link')){
                $content = $content .                                                   '<li><a href="' . $google_link . '" class="et_pb_font_icon et_pb_google_icon"><span>Google+</span></a></li>';
        }
        if(property_exists ($res1, 'linkedin_link')){
                $content = $content .                                                   '<li><a href="' . $linkedin_link . '" class="et_pb_font_icon et_pb_linkedin_icon"><span>LinkedIn</span></a></li>';
        }

        $content = $content .                                                   '</ul>    
                                                                </div> <!-- .et_pb_team_member -->
                                                                <div class="skill-set">';
                                                                if($res1->business_mngmnt_spprt) {$content = $content . '<h4>Business Management Support</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;


                                                                foreach($res1->business_mngmnt_spprt as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->social_media) {$content = $content . '<h4>Social Media</h4>';}
                                                                foreach($res1->social_media as $skill)
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;

                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->marketing) { $content = $content . '<h4>Marketing</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;                                                       

                                                                foreach($res1->marketing as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->communication) {$content = $content . '<h4>Communication</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;                                                

                                                                foreach($res1->communication as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->sales) {$content = $content . '<h4>Sales</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;                                                  
                                                                foreach($res1->sales as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->financial) {$content = $content . '<h4>Financial</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;                                                  
                                                                foreach($res1->financial as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->recruitment) {$content = $content . '<h4>Recruitment</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                        '<ul>' ;      
                                                                foreach($res1->recruitment as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->human_resource_mngmnt) {$content = $content . '<h4>Human Resource Management</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;   
                                                                foreach($res1->human_resource_mngmnt as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
                                                                if($res1->tooling) {$content = $content . '<h4>Tooling</h4>';}
                                                                $content = $content .                                                         '<ul>' ;                                                  

                                                                foreach($res1->tooling as $skill)
                                                                {
                                                                        $content = $content . '<li>' . $skill . '</li>';
                                                                }
        $content = $content .                                   '</ul>';
        foreach($res1->reviews as $review)
        {
                $content = $content .   '</div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <h2 class="review-section-title">Over VA '. $res1->name .'</h2>
                                        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_testimonial et_pb_testimonial_0 clearfix et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_left" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;" property="review" typeof="Review"> 
                                                <div class="et_pb_testimonial_portrait" style="background-image: url(http://vabusinessacademy.2citroenen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Schermafbeelding-2018-04-27-om-00.17.58.png);"> 
                                                </div> 
                                                <div class="et_pb_testimonial_description"> 
                                                        <div class="et_pb_testimonial_description_inner">
                                                                <div property="reviewRating" typeof="Rating"> 
                                                                    <span property="ratingValue">' .$review->rating.'<span>
                                                                    <span property="bestRating" style="display:none;">' .$review->rating_best.'</span>
                                                                    <span property="worstRating" style="display:none;">' .$review->rating_worst.'</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <meta property="datePublished" content='.$review->Created_date.'><span style="display:none;">'.$review->Created_date.'</span>
                                                                <p property="reviewBody">' . $review->text . '</p> 
                                                                <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
                                                                    <meta property="name" content='.$review->name.'>
                                                                </span>
                                                                <span style="display: none;" property="name">'. $res1->name . ' review, door: ' . $review->name.'</span>
                                                                <strong class="et_pb_testimonial_author" property="author" typeof="Person"><span property="name"' . $review->name . '</span></strong> 
                                                                <p class="et_pb_testimonial_meta">CEO, <a href="' . $review->website . '">' . $review->website . '</a></p> 
                                                        </div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial_description_inner --> 
                                                </div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial_description --> 
                                        </div> <!-- .et_pb_testimonial -->';                
        }

        $content = $content .                          '</div> <!-- .et_pb_column --> 
                                                </div> <!-- .et_pb_row --> 
                                        </div> <!-- .et_pb_section --> 
                                </div> <!-- .entry-content --> </div>  </div>';
        return $content;       
}

add_shortcode('add_va_profile_page','do_getVa');
?>
```

Comment: What is within your Chrome network log, can you see what resource is loading/causing the slow down? Please also test caching your API call using WP transients, ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: Thank you for the response. I 'Cleaned' up and seperated the shortcode code from this file. 

I didn't need shortcode either, because I wanted all CP to execute this code. 

Somehow after changing this I managed to fix the issue.


But now transfering to another server, I have another issue. It seems that connecting from the other server with my API directly doesn't work this way. 

Using wp_remote_get() gives issues when I try to reach IP:port/Route